# error: 'atoi' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++

I've searched high and low but nothing answers this specific issue. I am doing a coding assignment that functions perfectly as I want it to. However, per our instructors directions, we are not allowed to included the entire standard library, only specific functions (string, cout, etc.)

If I include 'stdlib.h' my code functions perfectly. If I remove that inclusion, I receive errors on these lines:

```
lid = atoi((input.substr(0, index1)).c_str());
```

> error: 'atoi' was not declared in this scope

```
lgpa = atof((input.substr(index1 + 1, (index2 - index1 - 1))).c_str());
```

> error: 'atof' was not declared in this scope

I have attempted to include these functions directly and receive the following errors:

```
lid = std::atoi((input.substr(0, index1)).c_str());
```

> error: 'atoi' is not a member of 'std'

```
lgpa = std::atof((input.substr(index1 + 1, (index2 - index1 - 1))).c_str());
```

> error: 'atof' is not a member of 'std'

Any constructive input would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `<stdlib.h>` (which has `atoi` etc) or `<cstdlib>` (which has `std::atoi` etc) are not "the entire standard library".  Despite the filename, these are only one of many similarly-sized chunks of the standard library.  In any case, throw away `atoi` and always use `strtod` instead.

Comment: maybe he meant not to do this: `using namespace std;`?
Thus if you need `cout` then you write `std::cout`...etc.

Comment: Earlier comment should have said -- Throw away `atoi` and use `strtol`, throw aray `atof` and use `strtod`.  Sorry for crossing the (integer and floating-point) streams.

Comment: you can just add `int atoi(const char *nptr);`